# Is it possible to determine iPhone model identifier?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to retrieve programmatically the iPhone model identifier (e.g. A1586), the one that is on the back side of the device.

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate. I am not looking for device model (e.g. iPhone 6) or device identifier (e.g. iPhone7,2). I need model identifier.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, I misread the top answer and thought output was like `"@"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5 (model A1428, AT&T/Canada)"`. Close Vote retracted :)